# How useful could be an html generator class?

Tags: php, html, github, code-generation

I'm working on my first opensource project, and I found useful do do an html generator class, treating the html elements as php objects, but now I don't know if it really makes sense in the real world.

Have you ever needed an html generator class for you projects?

If your answer is yes, what would you find useful on it?

If someone wants to help in the project, you are welcome to the repository on github.[Github repo](https://github.com/judasane/PHP-HTML-Generator)

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach, although liked by many at first sight, **always fails a reality check.**

Please learn about **templates** - the only way to go in dealing with HTML from PHP applications.

Comment: What about use it inside a template?

Comment: Look. HTML is not something ugly and limited to a few dozen tags with no attributes. It is a whole distinct field in the area of web-development. Distinct HTML designers working on it, adding CSS, JS, AJAX and many other stuff. So, you only job as a PHP programmer is to take a ready made HTML file and make a template out of it. Trying not to spoil the fine HTML programming done. There is jusdt no place for such a generator.

Answer (score 1):

You need them only if you are some outsourced worker from India or China. Otherwise do not use them since you have potential to ruin your career and credibility.

Those tools are built for doing very dirty code without any future prospects.